# How can I update a row in a DataTable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have the following code:

```
Dim i As Integer = dtResult.Rows.Count
For i = 0 To dtResult.Rows.Count Step 1
    strVerse = blHelper.Highlight(dtResult.Rows(i).ToString, s)
    ' syntax error here
    dtResult.Rows(i) = strVerse 
Next
```

I want to add a `strVerse` to the current row.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem you're running into is that you're trying to replace an entire row object.  That is not allowed by the DataTable API.  Instead you have to update the values in the columns of a row object.  Or add a new row to the collection.

To update the column of a particular row you can access it by name or index.  For instance you could write the following code to update the column "Foo" to be the value strVerse

```
dtResult.Rows(i)("Foo") = strVerse
```

Answer (score 10):

You can access columns by index, by name and some [other ways](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.item.aspx):

```
dtResult.Rows(i)("columnName") = strVerse
```

You should probably make sure your `DataTable` has some columns first...

Answer (score 8):

```
Dim myRow() As Data.DataRow
myRow = dt.Select("MyColumnName = 'SomeColumnTitle'")
myRow(0)("SomeOtherColumnTitle") = strValue
```

Code above instantiates a DataRow.  Where "dt" is a DataTable, you get a row by selecting any column (I know, sounds backwards).  Then you can then set the value of whatever row you want (I chose the first row, or "myRow(0)"), for whatever column you want.

Comment: Take care: in my experience this will update the copy of the row returned by select, not the original row inside the datatable

Comment: @Herbert I originally thought that, too, but the select is grabbing a row from the DataTable, it is not creating a copy of it or grabbing a row from a generic DataTable object. It is off of the "real thing". So when you set the value of the column on your selected row, you have a handle into the row you selected off of the original DataTable.

Comment: you are right, I tested it meanwhile. My earlier comment is not correct.